# Running multi server on one rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there anyway to run one application on 2 server? I try to use different port and pid file for each server

```
PORT=4000 rails s -P tmp/pids/server2.pid
rails s
```

but the first server alway restart after secend server running and show `A server is already running.` errors log

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't actually run the server twice in the same repository/folder as rails creates a `server.pid` file in `tmp/pids/` folder

```
cp /project /
```

What you can do is copy the project folder and then

```
cd /project/
rails s -p3000
```

and

```
cd /project_copy/
rails s -p4000
```

> **NOTE:** The advantage of this approach is you can run 2 servers on different branch as well

Comment: is there no way to run 2 server on same application?

Comment: Haven't came across one yet

Comment: whenever i need I just run it on two different folders

Comment: yah, but i need to run 2 server on one application to redunce a bugs :)

Comment: you will be running same code just in two different folders

Comment: nah this bug only can only redunce on 2 server of same application XD

Answer (score 0):

can you please try with this in your rails root app:

```
cd /rails_project/
rails s -p 3007 -P 42342
```

then open new tab in terminal

```
cd /rails_project/
rails s -p 3000 -P 42340
```

Comment: first you kill all running pid for that rails or stop current rails server. then run again. 

`$ lsof -wni tcp:3000`
`$ kill -9 PID`

then run above code again

Comment: I got same result, 1 server said `Address already in use`, another said `A server is already running. Check 42342.`

Comment: did you stop current rails server? did you kill all running PID under that port? weird, mine is working fine

Comment: yes, i already kill all server and PID, delete all PID file and already restart my PC but still got same errors